# Компонент: восстановление пароля. Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте. Не могу все никак освоить эту горе-систему, возможно не мое, но надо. Задача состоит в следующем: создать компонент, который при восстановлении пароля генерирует новый пароль (длина от 7 до 10 символов), устанавливает его для пользователя и отсылает его вместо стандартного уведомления. Натолкните кто на разумную мысль.

Comment: А чем не устраивает кастомизация стандартного компонента system.auth.forgotpasswd ?

Comment: А тем, что надо реализовать именно вышеизложенный процесс, а как, не знаю. Думал переработать этот стандартный компонент, но не выходит

Comment: А в чем конкретно не получалось переработать стандартный компонент? "Думал" и "Пытался" -- всё-таки немного разные вещи